# best way to redirect a web page

Tags: html, redirect

what is the best way to redirect a website regarding to:
- SEO efforts (don't want search engine to freak out because of a minor change)
- compatible with all browsers

Comment: What is your server backend?

Comment: Read this: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

Answer (score 1):

*(based off of question 'best way').*

**1.)** Put this at the *top* of your (`.php`) document. *(.php needs to be the file extension)*

```
<?php  header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;  ?>
```

[**Tutorial**](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm).

**2.)** If your document is `.html` you have this option or you can use javaScript. *(.html can be the file extension)*

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.indiana.edu/~account/new-directory">
```

[**Tutorial**](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml).

---

*The PHP option is a better approach.*

Comment: How do you know he's using PHP?

Comment: He asked for the best way. PHP is IMO. I offered a HTML solution as well. He didn't specify.

Comment: Exactly. Better to ask

Comment: Well. I disagree. That's what the question asked. I felt I answered appropriately.

Comment: HTML only was inferred with the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, for SEO optimization, you want to use a **301 Redirect**.

To quote [this Mozilla Article](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection):

> the 301 redirect is preferable for both users and search engines. Serving a 301 indicates to both browsers and search engine bots that the page has moved permanently. Search engines interpret this to mean that not only has the page changed location, but that the content—or an updated version of it—can be found at the new URL. The engines will carry any link weighting from the original page to the new URL

How to implement such a redirect is a different question and is dependent on your server environment and development platform. But googling "how to do a 301 redirect with [insert your technology of choice]" should get you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect a web page

> ```
>        <?php
>            echo "<script>";
>            echo "location.replace('latest.php?mess=addnotsuccess')";
>            echo "</script>";
>        ?>
> ```

Comment: where do I insert this (i'm new to this)

Comment: why do you echo script?

Comment: echo "location.replace('latest.php?mess=addnotsuccess')";      in this line 'lestest' should be replaced with the new url ?

Comment: Try this     header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: How do you know he's using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

> ```
>         if($id)
>         {
>            echo "<script>";
>            echo "location.replace('student_marks.php?mess=addsuccess&student_id={$id}')";
>            echo "</script>";
>         }
>         else
>         {
>           echo "<script>";
>           echo "location.replace('latest.php?mess=addnotsuccess')";
>           echo "</script>";
>         }
> ```

Comment: How do you know he's using PHP?

Comment: John - it's better to edit your original answer with additional info, rather than post multiple answers. Might i suggest you edit one and delete the other...